# HTML: How to set iframe's src with a javascript variable or function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have three html files, the html(#1) is the menu page that shows images of 3D models where users could click and and direct them to html(#2) with the description of that 3D model.

As you can see this "href" also carries some parameters that html(#3) needs to position the camera view for the users to see an specific angle of the 3D model.
Now, the html(#2) which it's description page has html(#3) on an iframe.

I would like to have html(#2) be able to receive these parameters from html(#1) and pass it to html(#3).

I thought that by declaring the src this way: "document.getElementById("pooliframe").src = address;" it would write on iframe's src tag the address variable, but I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
for this code line: document.getElementById("pooliframe").src = address;

***Please help me, please!!!***

Comment: `document.getElementById('pooliframe').src = 'urlhere';` - This is all you need, you need to make sure your other code is effectively running and calling this properly.

Comment: It's best to try searching for the text of the error first. There are usually many questions which reference it and can help you find your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you include your scripts *after* the actual `#pooliframe` element. `getElementById` possibly returns you `null` because the element does not yet exist. This snippet demonstrates:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This will log `null` because #pooliframe does not exist here.
  console.log(document.getElementById('pooliframe'));
</script>

<iframe id="pooliframe" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // But it does exist here:
  console.log(document.getElementById('pooliframe'));
</script>
```

If you try to write a property `src` to `null` you'll get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

**Try it:**

```js
// Obviously "pooliframe" does not exist without HTML:
document.getElementById("pooliframe").src = 'some-address';
```

If you have no control over the element order within the HTML you can also use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to defer execution of a script until the DOM is fully parsed:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('pooliframe'));
  })
</script>

<iframe id="pooliframe" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeffrey!! I didn't notice this mistake! It works now!!